# быстрый метод для создания анаграмм на JS без библиотек

Tags: javascript

есть код для поиска анаграмм, получаю массив всех анаграмм, сортирую его и беру индекс анаграмму из массива, которая соответствует исходному слову. Но есть проблема, для длинных слов код работает очень медленно, может кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой? буду рад советам и помощи!

```
function listPosition(word) { 
 var arr = [word]; 
 var anagrams = {}; 
 arr.forEach(function(str) { 
 var recurse = function(ana, str) { 
  if (str === '') 
   anagrams[ana] = 1;
   for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
   recurse(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1)); 
  }; 
   recurse('', str); 
}); 
  var result = Object.keys(anagrams); 
  return result.sort().indexOf(word) + 1; 
} 

console.log(listPosition('BOOKKEEPER'));
```

Comment: Задавая вопрос, приводите входные данные, что у Вас вышло и что **ожидается**.

Comment: при больших словах скрипт выполняется очень долго, может есть какой-то способ быстрого составления анаграмм?

Comment: Повторюсь: вход (`1, 2`), Ваши действия (`a + a + b`), полученный Вами выход (`4`) и выход, какой Вам нужен (`3`). Мы же можем подправить (`a + b`).

Comment: при вызвове с 'BOOKKEEPER' код выполняется приверно 1,5 секунды, а если 'BOOKKEEPERMASTER' то выполнене свыше 10 секунд, есть ли какой то способ ускорить процесс составления анаграмм?

Comment: задача стоит такая: на вход есть слово, например question, из него нужно составить анаграммы, полученный массив отсортировать по алфавиту и найти анаграмму в массиве, равную исходному слову и вернуть его индекс, все работает хорошо для слов не больше 7 символов, потом процесс компиляции слишком долгий, мне нужно в пределах 10 секунд для.

Comment: дай определение термину: анаграмма

Comment: есть слово например ABAB, из него делаю набор анаграмм, т.е --> ["AABB","ABAB","ABBA","BAAB","BABA","BBAA"]. вот потом нахожу элемент массива который равен исходному слову и вывожу его индекс

Comment: При построении своих анаграмм, вы по сути находите все перестановки символов слова. А это N! (N - размер слова в символах). Для  5 -- 120, для 10 уже 3628800. Понятно, что в этой программе вы таким способом преобразуете слово в число, которое будет уникально для всех возможных слов заданного размера, составленных из тех же букв, что и данное слово. Скорее всего для решения такой задачи нужен какой-то другой подход (взятие хэш-функции?). Кстати, а *основная задача* в чем состоит (зная ее, можно посоветовать что-то адекватное)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно научиться считать общее число анаграмм слова.
Потом можно рекурсивно считать количество лексикографически меньших анаграмм.

```js
const fact = n => n<2?n:n*fact(n-1);

const wordletters = word => word.split('').sort()
  .reduce((res,letter) => 
    (res[letter]=(res[letter]|0)+1, res), {});

const objVals = obj => 
  Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key => obj[key]);

// Общее число всех анаграмм
// n! / (n₀!*n₁!*n₂!*...nₖ!)
const anaCount = word => 
  fact(word.length)
  /
  objVals(wordletters(word))
    .map(fact)
    .reduce((c, a) => c*a, 1);

const anaIndex = word => {
  let count = 0;
  let letters = Object.keys(wordletters(word)).sort();
  let index = letters.indexOf(word[0]);
  let lesser = letters.slice(0, index); // буквы меньшие первой
  lesser.forEach(letter => {
    // Считаем все, начинающиеся на letter
    let set = word.split('');
    // исключаем letter
    set.splice(set.indexOf(letter), 1);
    count += anaCount(set.join(''));
  });
  // рекурсия от слова без первой буквы
  if (word.length > 1) count += anaIndex(word.substr(1));
  return count;
};

console.log(anaCount('BOOKKEEPER'));       // 151200
console.log(anaIndex('BOOKKEEPER'));       // 10742
console.log(anaIndex('BOOKKEEPERMASTER')); // 10991405956
```

[ES5](https://es6console.com/izxwjf0s/)

Comment: а если на ES6?заранее спасибо!

Comment: В смысле на es5?

Comment: https://es6console.com/izxuftqa/

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Но ведь это пока не решает задачу, только указывает путь)

Comment: я и не просил написать код, а просил совет)

Answer (score 0):

```
let words = ['cider','study', 'angel', 'chin','cried', 'glean', 'dusty','inch']

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

  let word = words[i];
  let alphabetical = word.split("").sort().join("");

  for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

    if (i === j) {
      continue;
    }

    let other = words[j];
    if (alphabetical === other.split("").sort().join("")) {
      console.log(word + " = " + other);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]